# How to implement DEEPExpectation (DEX) age detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, imdb

First of all, I'm new to the **Deep Learning** platform, please correct me if I did any mistake.

I'm trying to implement the age detection by using [DEX](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/en/publications/papers/articles/eth_biwi_01299.pdf) method. As of now my understand is that, they tried to train a CNN weight model using VGG-16 architechture. I'm using **IMDB_WIKI** dataset as they suggest in their paper.

I'm using **TensorFlow, Keras** to train my weight model in **Python3** language.

My Steps to train the model(I just starts with the IMDB set):

1. Load the **IMDB mat** file and get training data and validation data set(10% of total dataset)
2. Create a **VGG-16** model with **ImageNet** weight(I belive its a large dataset)
3. As **ImageNet** have 1000 classes, remove the last layer of model and put my single age class output layer instead.
4. Also add a dropout layer on the top of output layer(frankly don't know how it is working)

**My experiment start from here :)**

1. Freeze the layers alreay pretrain into VGG-16 architechture, except my new added layers, now there are some non-trainable objects available. In that case my training age accuracy is just 19% which is too poor, i hope detecting real age it should be 50-56%.
2. By seeing that I guess that may be due to, I didn't train all the layers. I remove the freezeness of the layers and tried to train but it's showing me a out of memory exception, After that I have just freeze 8 layers of my total architecture, after training 40 epochs I found that age accuracy is 11% which is less that before :(

**Can any one please help me to understand this paper properly, please ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Also add a dropout layer on the top of output layer(frankly don't know how it is working)"  - That is just plainly wrong. A dropout layer sets multiplies the output with 0, making the activation and the gradient 0. If you use this as your final layer with k percent, then your result will be rubbish in k percent of cases, e.g. dropping your accuracy. Just remove it and it should be better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Thomas for your help. I removed that dropout layer, and it started with 17%, it was my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

It is already implemented in deepface package for python

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
obj = DeepFace.analyze("img1.jpg", actions = ["age", "gender"])
print(obj)
```

The model is trained based on the instructions of DEX paper. It builds a VGG model in the background and loads pre-trained weights. Besides, it runs on TensorFlow framework and Keras APIs.